# Flag overlay does not display in spite of pending flags if the post is deleted

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, deleted-answers, flags

A new problem seems to have surfaced, in which the flag overlay will refuse to display for a post if the post is currently deleted, even if there are pending flags (for instance, flags that were raised by 10k users or the author post-deletion). This prevents me from handling the flags from the question page.

The flags will remain visible and accessible from the moderator queue, so as a workaround they can still be handled from the queue as long as I'm looking at the queue. However when I follow the link to the question page to see the Q&A in full, the flag overlay does not display for that answer.

The flag overlay will display normally and allow me to handle the flags from the question page if I undelete the answer, and in general as long as the answer isn't deleted. The problem *only* manifests when the answer is currently deleted and it has pending flags.

Reproduced on [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12529/a-question-on-the-very-essence-of-theoretical-computer-science), where there is a flag on one of the answers that came in with the migration and were automatically deleted and locked when the migration was rejected. But only sometimes (unless the bug's just been fixed): two days ago I couldn't get the overlay to show up, today I can't get it not to show up!

Comment: Can't repro on The Workplcae (flagged one of my deleted answers, it shows up fine).

Comment: Norepro: http://i.stack.imgur.com/I57Z5.png

Comment: Can you link to an example where this problem happens?